# Entering Japan on a temporary passport

Tags: passports, japan, customs-and-immigration

I will be flying to Japan using a temporary "emergency"-type passport. These are not biometric, as they do not contain a chip with fingerprints inside them.

Has any citizen from either Italy, Poland, Portugal, Romania or Austria  visited Japan lately and entered it with one of those passports?

I'm asking to see if there might be any special circumstances that may apply at the airport if one arrives with those passports (e.g. getting a nastier entry-interview after landing or being taken more in-depth biometrics)

Comment: You really seem freaked out by this travel to Japan. Relax. It's a pleasant country.

Comment: I think that in terms of border control, the USA is much more exotic than Japan, not what you might have expected :)

Comment: Why those specific countries? Surely you're not a quadruple national who lost all their passports at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

Whilst at immigration at Narita back in late 2012, I spoke to an Austrian in front of me who was on a *Notpass* (which is white), and she had the same experience as me (ordinary Swedish passport): just a quick photo match, scan of the passport, fingerprint and photo taking and then getting the entry sticker.

Entry interview? None, as the officer clearly didn't speak English, and although I do speak Japanese, I did not show it even by a "Konnichiwa" to speeden things up.

Comment: Do you know that the person didn't have, for example, a tourist visa in their *Notpass*?

Comment: @fkraiem I don't know that for a fact, but she was only staying for tourism for a week, so highly doubt it. It's not like it's required.